# Represent an array of a model in Ember

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am writing a Music player Component with favorites songs from SoundCloud using their API

I want automatically play the next favorite song once the previous is finished.

The idea is to create a new property to represent an array of all my favorites to pass the nextFavorite

This is my player controller

```
sortedFavorites: Ember.computed.alias('favorites’),
```

and

```
actions: {
    selectFavorite: function(favorite, index, play) {
            if (!this.get('externalPlay')) {
                index = index + 1;
                nextFavorite = this.get('sortedFavorites').nextObject(index, favorite);
                self.set('nextFavorite', nextFavorite);
            }
            return SC.stream(favoritePath, {
                onfinish: function() {
                    self.set('isPlaying', false);
                    if (self.get('nextFavorite') != null) {
                        return self.send('selectFavorite', self.get('nextFavorite'), index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

When i create a new property the alias for “favorites” , it is undefined

[image]

In case i create an alias for a single favorite i can access to my single favorite although it’s not what i need to do

[image]

My problem is that the favorite model doesn't have `DS.hasMany` pointing to a `DS.Model`

so i don't know how to figure it

This is the favorite model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Favorite = DS.Model.extend({
    duration: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    genre: DS.attr('string'),
    artwork_url: DS.attr('string'),
    uri: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('user')
});

export default Favorite;
```

so how can the sortedFavorites be an array of all my favorites in order to access to the nextObject (favorite)?

The Route

```
var MusicRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    needs: ['player'],
    player: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.player'),
    beforeModel: function() {
        return SC.initialize({
            client_id: window.soundcloud_api_key,
            redirect_url: '#'
        });
    },
    model: function(params) {
        var artist, self, ret;
        self = this;
        artist = params.artist;
        ret = [];
        this.controllerFor('application').set('artistName', artist);

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return SC.get("/users/" + 'mannaio' + "/favorites", {
                limit: 40
            }, function(favorites) {
                if (favorites.length) {
                    favorites.forEach(function(item) {
                        var favorite;
                        favorite = self.createFavoritelist(item);
                        ret.push(favorite);
                        favorite.user = self.createUser(item.user);
                    });
                    resolve(ret);                
                } else {
                  return reject(self.errorHandler(artist));
                }
            });
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var favorite ;
        this._super(controller, model);
        favorite = model.get('firstObject');
        this.controllerFor('player').set('favorite', favorite).send('selectFavorite', favorite, 0, false);
        return controller;
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this._super();
        return this.render('player', {
            into: 'music',
            outlet: 'player',
            controller: 'player'
        });
    },
    createFavoritelist: function(favorite) {
        return this.store.createRecord('favorite', {
            id: favorite.id,
            title: favorite.title,
            duration: favorite.duration,
            uri: favorite.uri,
            artwork_url: favorite.artwork_url,
            genre: favorite.genre,
        });
    },
    createUser: function(user) {
        return this.store.createRecord('user', {
            username: user.username,
            avatar_url: user.avatar_url,
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide more input in what is 'favorites' ? the alias is prob working, it might be a problem with what 'favorites is' can you perhaps also add your model hook from the router here?

Comment: The model is hooked with a promise     model: function(params) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return SC.get("/users/" + 'mannaio' + "/favorites", {
                limit: 40
            }

Comment: What's SC? if you're using Ember data, why aren't you just calling the store? Can you perhaps also paste your router code above?

Comment: SC is for soundcloud , i have attached the route, my player component is in player  template though

Comment: It looks like you're returning a controller from the setupController? you don't need to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like favorites is not really defined?

Maybe do an alias on the model (if you want an alias) or a copy if not?

Also you don't have to return a controller from setupController..

try setting up the model on the favorites controller?

```
self.controllerFor('player').set('favorites', model);
```

In your setup controller, so you don't need the second alias.

If that doesn't work, you can also try having the player controller access the music controller (I assume that's the music controller)
Add:

```
needs : 'music'
```

which then you should have access to the music controller:

```
this.get('controller.music.model') -> favorites
```

to the play controller, and you should have access to the music model, which looks like your favorites..

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Comment: SetupController is to set up the first favorite in my player component once the page is loaded. The alias on the model sortedFavorites: Ember.computed.alias('model') returns null